# How To Amend Value of a Duplicate Entry in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have a set of data in a Google Sheets column which may contain a series of duplicates in random locations.
Each time a duplicate is encountered, I would like to programatically add a unique character to the entry which then makes it unique again. The order of the data CANNOT be changed / sorted.
i.e.

- GGG
- TTT
- FFF
- GGG
- GGG

would become

- GGG
- TTT
- FFF
- GGG^
- GGG^^

The result of the query CAN be written out into a parallel column rather than changing the original data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe:

[image]

So in `B1`:

```
=A1&REPT("^",COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option that uses numbers instead of symbols and may keep the entry in `B` a little shorter if you have many duplicates:
`=ArrayFormula(IF(A:A<>"",IF((IF(A:A<>"",INT(COUNTIF(A:A,A:A)>1),""))=1,A:A & (IF(A:A<>"",ROW(A2:A)-1,"")),A:A),""))`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(A2:A6), A2:A6&rept("^", countifs(A2:A6, A2:A6, row(A2:A6), "<="&row(A2:A6))-1),))
```

[image: Screenshort]